# Locked out by pamd. Help!

Tags: login, pam

I recently changed some `pamd` settings because I wanted my ssh keys unlocked at login. I followed the instructions at this [wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_Keys#pam_ssh).

Ignoring the warning, I have become locked out (cannot log in with user account or even root also in safe mode).

How can this be fixed?
I have a live CD for arch linux, but I`m hoping a reinstall is not necessary.

Comment: Boot from live CD.  Mount your root partition (e.g. `mount /dev/sda2 /mnt`).  Edit PAM configs under `/mnt/etc/pam.d`).

Comment: heh that easy! why do we go trough all the trouble of securing our pc's. Let's hope this works.

Comment: Many of us go through loads of trouble securing computers *physically* too, because once someone has physical access to the console, much of logical security is largely irrelevant. But it's still a whole lot easier to do it over the network than to travel to your location with a large hammer (or a rescue CD and bad intentions). :)

Comment: This is why [system encryption](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/System_Encryption_with_LUKS) (i.e. encrypting the root file system) is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be fixed with a CD as Mikel suggested, but you can also do this without a CD.

1. You can pass `init=/bin/sh` as an argument to the kernel (in the bootloader) to launch a shell.
2. Once you have the shell, do `mount -o remount,rw /` to remount the root filesystem read/write.
3. Edit the pam config to fix the issue.
4. Reboot

**Note** this procedure is dependent upon your distribution. If you have a distribution which ships with a special initramfs, then `init=/bin/sh` might not work. In this case you should look up how to get a rescue shell in the initramfs (in your distro's documentation).